# Flexible table according to a cell size

Tags: html, css, cell, css-tables

I have tables like this:

```
   ------------------------------------------------
  |   product-name                   | icon | text |
   ------------------------------------------------
  |   product-info                   | icon | text |
   ------------------------------------------------
```

I want my cells to be flexible according to the last cell content:

```
   ------------------------------------------------
  |   product-name                      | ic | smt |
   ------------------------------------------------
  |   product-info                      | ic | smt |
   ------------------------------------------------

   -------------------------------------------------
  |   product-name                | icon | big-text |
   -------------------------------------------------
  |   product-info, bla bla bla...| icon | text     |
   -------------------------------------------------
```

I tried this css:

```
  table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  table td:nth-child(1) {
    max-width: 70%;
  }

  table td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 10%;
  }

  table td:nth-child(3) {
    max-width: 20%;
  }
```

I put `table-layout:fixed`, but I can't manage to make the max-width to work. And I don't know how to tell that the last cell is the one to determine the others size.

The `product-info` content can be very big and I applied an ellipsis it become too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is get rid of `table-layout: fixed`, because that does the opposite of what you want. For the rest, if you want tables to be flexible, don't try to force widths on them!

There's a little trick to make some table cells as wide as their content, while giving the remaining cells the rest of the remaining space: make their width `1px` and make sure that they can't wrap by setting `white-space: nowrap`. Then the rest will come naturally.

```css
table {
  border: 1px outset;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px inset;
}

table td:nth-child(2),
table td:nth-child(3) {
  white-space:nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>product-name</td>
    <td>ic</td>
    <td>smt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>product-info</td>
    <td>ic</td>
    <td>smt</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>product-name</td>
    <td>icon</td>
    <td>big-text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>product-info, bla bla bla...</td>
    <td>ic</td>
    <td>smt</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this is what you meant!

Comment: Thank you, I did the trick with your idea.
I used max-width: 1px because otherwise the table length would be bigger than the container-frame.